# Not allowed users are authentication in my Azure AD Application Multi Tenant

Tags: azure, authentication, c#-4.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have two tenants configured in my Azure AD. My users are authentication with successful in my tenant but others users that are another tenant has access in my applications.

What's wrong with my application? I'm using OpenId Connect protocol in my code, for exemple:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                },
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                    {
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Am I setting something wrong on my Azure?

Someone help me?

Thanks,

Vilela

Comment: It is not clear to me what issue you are running into here. Can you please copy and paste the error message you are receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have two tenants configured in my Azure AD.

The tenants are corresponding to the Azure Active Directory. So when there are two tenants that means you have two different Azure Active Directory.( refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj573650.aspx) about the detail concept)

And to enable the multi-tenat app, we need to enable it from the [old Azure portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/) and locat you app. Then you can set it by refering the figure below:
[image]

### Update( limit the sepcifc tenants to access the multi-tenants app)

```
 app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = ClientId,
                    Authority = Authority,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        // instead of using the default validation (validating against a single issuer value, as we do in line of business apps), 
                        // we inject our own multitenant validation logic
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                    },
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {                    
                        // we use this notification for injecting our custom logic
                        SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                        {
                            // retriever caller data from the incoming principal
                            string issuer = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("iss").Value;    
                            var issuer1 = "";
                            var issuer2 = "";
                            if ((issuer!=issuer1)&& (issuer != issuer2))
                            // the caller was neither from a trusted issuer - throw to block the authentication flow
                            throw new SecurityTokenValidationException();                            
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                       }
                   }
              });
```

Comment: Thank you Fei Xue, but when I have application configured with multi tenant, all others users that have Azure Account can come in my application. I need to allow only my tenants (In case two tenants). Tks.

Comment: The mullti-tenant application is enable all the tenants on Azure AD by default, If you want to limit the tenants you need to custom the token validation. I modified the orignal post to append the code sample.

Comment: That's okay Fei Xue. The Multi-Tenant option is not safe in my opinion and in my scenario, but it's works well when I get the tenant and compare with the my tenants. I think better to put my tenants and clientId codes in my web.config and switch it after app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication code when I get the app.Properties["host.AppName"] that is in my IIS. I can’t thank you enough for everything you’ve done! It was a pleasure. Tks

Comment: @Vilela You are welcome. And if the reply is helpful to resolve the issue, please consider accepting it as an answer so that other communities who have the same issue could recognize the answer easily.

Comment: Do you know how to use the same authentication Azure AD with Win.Forms? Can I use the same protocol UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication?

Comment: We are able to integrate Azure AD with web app or native app via OAuth 2.0/OpenIdConnect. However, `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` is a comment which need to [OWIN](http://owin.org/) which is used to  decouple **web server** and application support.  In a native desktop application, we can use the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` library to integrate Azure AD. [Here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-desktop) is a code sample wrote using WPF for your reference.